# How to color values greater than particular values in Histogram

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have plotted a histogram chart using d3 in that I have called values using json. I want to color values which are greater than some value.

```
d3.json('stk.json', function (data) {
            // just to have some space around items. 

        data =   $.each(data.stackoverflow,function(i,stack){

                 return {bucket: stack.x1, N: stack.y};      
            });     


         x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.x1; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.y; })]);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, "+(height-pad)+")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+(left_pad-pad)+", 0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x', function (d) { return x(d.x1); })
        .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
        .attr('y', height-pad)
        .transition()
        .delay(function (d) { return d.x1*20; })
        .duration(800)
        .attr('y', function (d) { return y(d.y); })
        .attr('height', function (d) { return height-pad - y(d.y); })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.y); });

});
```

could someone help me with it.

Comment: Please give examples....

Answer (score 0):

your answer is right there on this lien

`.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.y); });`

just provide your logic in side of that function and make sure you return the appropriate color for example lets say you want all the bars over 5 to be red you just do

`.style("fill", function(d) { 
    return d.y>5 ? '#ff0000' : color(d.y); 
});`

hope this helps